# cannot find the name com in native script

Tags: angular, nativescript

I addeded my third party *.jar file in `app/App_Resources/android/libs/*.jar` folder.

I imported the package like `const leopardPkg = com.leopard.api;`

Now I am getting the error like `cannot find the name com`. can anyone tell me how to import the package correctly.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error, this could just be a typescript issue since TS doesn't know the structure of `com.leopard.api` and then a simple fix is to make sure you declare `com` so TS knows you know what you're doing or cast the type to `any`. If you're getting an exception thrown then it's a build issue and the library isn't being built into the app correctly.

Comment: thanks @BradMartin. After adding the *.jar file I build the app by `tns build android`. I declared com like `declare var com: any;` and I accessed the api like `com.leopard.api`. Now I am getting the error like `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined`. can you please help me where I am Making the mistake.

Comment: Well, `com` is the root namespace used for core Java packages so I guess your library is in conflict with the com namespace used by Java as `leopard` is `undefined`. Are you sure your library main namespace is `com` ?

Comment: thanks @NickIliev, I just have *.jar file but `I dont't know the exact name space`. `Is there any possibility of finding the namespace`. when I decompiled the *.jar file I found all *.java files in `com/leopard/api folder`. So, I thought com.leopard.api is the name space

Comment: it would be nice to add a reference to library so we can check the code there

Comment: I also used the command `jar -tf LeopardProwessSdkV-1.1.9.jar | more` to find the name space. I got the following output `com/leopard/api/i.class
com/leopard/api/j.class
com/leopard/api/k.class
com/leopard/api/MagCard$a.class
com/leopard/api/MagCard$b.class
com/leopard/api/MagCard.class
com/leopard/api/af.class
com/leopard/api/ac.class
com/leopard/api/a.class

-- more --`